# Image capture issue through camera in Android kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera

I'm trying to capture image  by two ways one is by camera intent and and another is by contract launcher as onActivity is depreciated. But I am  getting following issue

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3188456 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:263)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8276)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3188456 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:568)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4429)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
```

HERE IS MY CODE THROUGH INTENT

```
fun openCamera(activity: Activity): Intent {
    //camera intent
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    // set filename
    val imgFile = createImageFile(activity)
    val imgURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.applicationContext, authr, imgFile)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgURI)
    return cameraIntent

}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createImageFile(activity: Activity): File {

    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
     val storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName, // prefix
        ".jpg", // suffix
        storageDir      // directory
    )

    return image
}
```

CODE THROUGH CONTRACT

```
private val contract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
        
        viewBinding.imgUserProfile.setImageURI(null)
        viewBinding.imgUserProfile.setImageURI(imageUri)
    }
```

Getting same issue from both methods

Comment: Its just the object of contentvalues

Comment: That's the code to open the device camera and fetch the image data but when this code open the camera application crashes in background with the above mention error .

Comment: Ok updated but can you flag out the issue

Comment: The code you posted will not produce an android.os.TransactionTooLargeException . Find the real code please.